# Need help: GPA calculator C++

Tags: c++

I need to write a code that calculates a GPA, it needs to have this caracteristics:

1. Capture 4 ratings (ratings) entered by the user.
2. Get the average of the notes, all have equal weight, and display it in screen
3. If the student averages 80 or more, display a message "absolved"
4. If the average is greater than or equal to 45 and less than 80 display a
   message "exam"
5. If the average is less than 45 display a message "failed"

I´m just a begginer so i need help.
Here's code that i wrote but it shows the error "error: cannot find 'ld'" (I'm working whith Code::Blocks in Windows 10)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float calificacion_1, calificacion_2, calificacion_3, calificacion_4;
    printf("Ingrese calificacion 1: ");
    scanf("%f", &calificacion_1);
    printf("Ingrese calificacion 2: ");
    scanf("%f", &calificacion_2);
    printf("Ingrese calificacion 3: ");
    scanf("%f", &calificacion_3);
    printf("Ingrese calificacion 4: ");
    scanf("%f", &calificacion_4);
    if ((calificacion_1 + calificacion_2 + calificacion_3 + calificacion_4) / 4 >= 70)
        printf("aprueba\n");
    else
        printf("reprueba\n");
    putchar('\n');
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Also I don't know how to apply the points 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: Are you being taught this as C++?  If so run away.  The only C++ part of this is `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` which are not even being used.

Comment: With a little more effort, you could search the internet using the keywords "stackoverflow c++ grade calculator" or use "gpa" instead of grade.

Comment: Please make your program more readable by adding spaces between operators, such as `calificacion_1 + calification_2`.

Comment: This is using C input/output in what is meant to be a C++ program; choose either one. Other than that, it's a grave mistake to divide by `4` and not `4.f` (look up integer vs float division). Finally, starting to learn C or C++ programming on Windows is a silly thing to do, to be straight.

Comment: Now. "It shows the error" <- until you understand what is "it" and can describe it precisely, you're not moving forward. Want to be an engineer, learn to be precise and know the internals. In this exact case, the error is caused by a broken compiler setup, and has nothing to do with the code you've written. Fix the compiler installation first.

Answer (score 0):

just do one thing re install code-blocks..it worked for me..Also i ran your code on dev-c++ which ran fine...so i recommend you to install dev-c++

Answer (score 0):

declare  average variable

```
float average;       

 average=calificacion_1+calificacion_2+calificacion_3+calificacion_4)/4;
if(average>=80)
{
 printf("\nAbsolved");
}
else if(average>=45 && average<80)
{
 printf("\nExam");
}
else
{
printf("\nFail");
}
```